# Linq with MongDB Error with Where Clause

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mongodb, linq

I have this code:

```
Imports MongoDB.Bson
Imports MongoDB.Driver
Imports MongoDB.Driver.Linq

Public Class Principal

Private Sub Find

    Dim mongo As New MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
    Dim db = mongo.GetDatabase("test")

    Dim Tipos = db.GetCollection(Of TipoDeIdentificacion).("TiposDeIdentificacion")
```

These work fine:

```
Dim query = Tipos.AsQueryable.OrderByDescending(Function(X) X.id).ToList
Dim query1 = Tipos.AsQueryable.Where(Function(X)  x.Nombre.Contains("DNI")).ToList
```

These doesn't work:

```
Dim query2 = Tipos.AsQueryable.Where(Function(X) X.Nombre = "DNI").ToList
```

Exception thrown:

> CompareString({document}{Nombre}, "DNI", False) is not supported.

¿Any idea?

Comment: Yoiu can download and study the following code: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-started-with-37dbd5bd

Answer (score 2):

In the Mongo Linq Drivers, the Equality Operator does not work with string... It makes no sense.
I use "Is" Instead and it works fine

```
Function(X) X.Nombre Is "DNI"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that MongoDB C# driver not really support VB.NET. That's why the name is C# driver (not .Net Driver).

BTW:
Is (instead of = ) and IsNot (instead of <>) works just find.

The problem is > or < has no equivalence (As of CompareString in VB that has -1, 0 or 1).

So, in this moment, MongoDB C# Linq is not fully works with VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution!

In the class TipoDeIdentificacion, id was declared Nullable(of Long).

There should be some kind process integrated inside the C# driver to manage equality with nullable fields.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same probem. 
For me, this code works

```
Dim query2 = Tipos.AsQueryable.Where(Function(X) X.Nombre.Equals("DNI")).ToList
```